# jQuery custom toggle function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a custom jQuery toggle function. Right now, I have 2 separate functions, `lightsOn` and `lightsOff`. How can I combine these functions to make them toggle (so I can just link to one function)?

```
function lightsOn(){
 $('#dim').fadeOut(500,function() {
   $("#dim").remove();
 });
};

function lightsOff(){
 $('body').append('<div id="dim"></div>');
 $('#dim').fadeIn(250);
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function toggleLights()
{
    var $dim = $('#dim');
    if ($dim.length)
    {
        $dim.fadeOut(500, function ()
        {
            $dim.remove();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $dim = $('<div/>', {id: 'dim'});
        $('body').append($dim);
        $dim.fadeIn(250);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/hxL8s/

Answer (score 2):

```
function toggleLights(){
    if ($("body").has("#dim")) {
        $('#dim').fadeOut(500, function() {
           $("#dim").remove();
        });
    } else {
        $('body').append('<div id="dim"></div>');
        $('#dim').fadeIn(250);
   }
}
```

Comment: Meh, you really don't need to keep re-querying the DOM for `#dim`.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for the help, however it doesn't work for me. (The one from MДΓΓ БДLL does, however.)

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - true - I doubt it would ever matter - especially since you're querying by id.  Besides, to optimize it I'd basically be copying your answer :)